# How nativescript handles session-based api automatically?

Tags: angular, nativescript

So my company decided that we will create an app that will still use our session based API (meaning the cookies / sessions should be sent back and forth).

As Im writing the app and start to request to the api I noticed that it handles the cookies / sessions pretty well without me doing anything (e.g storing data somewhere). I supposed that nativscript doesn't use any browser implicitly. If so, how it handles the cookies in my situation?

Thank!

Comment: Yes, {NS} does not use browser and converts your code into native elements. Fot http , you can refer here

Comment: @Narendra where?

Comment: sorry, missed the link https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ng-framework-modules/http

Comment: Yeah already checked that. What I am asking is where do {N} stores cookies?

Comment: Note: I am not using any token based auth only session based

Comment: I think it stors inside app storage only but you can't control it as that feature is still not supported. https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2424

Comment: Yeah, I have to navigate through the source code. It is somehow storing it somwehere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193746/discussion-between-narendra-and-iamjc015).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NativeScript does not store it anywhere (except in memory).

For you to save your sessions for longer term, you need to parse the headers on return of a HTTP and pull the values out that you need and then re-inflate the cookies (and other needed headers) on your first connection on a new application start.